# Tornado gzip compressed response for a specific RequestHandler

Tags: python, tornado

How can I serve compressed responses only for a single RequestHandler from my Tornado application?

Answer (score 2):

In that handler's `initialize()` method, call `self.transforms.append(tornado.web.GZipContentEncoding)`

Comment: RequestHandler doesn't contain a `transforms` attribute, instead it has a `_transforms` attribute witch is overwritten in `_execute` method.

Comment: Oops, I was looking at `Application`. There's not a clean way to use GZipContentEncoding then; you'll need to gzip the data by hand before writing it.